# How to run a node app in bluehost cpanel?

Tags: node.js, cpanel, mern, shared-hosting, bluehost

I am using the basic bluehost hosting plan to deploy a Node app (MERN).

Because node is not installed, I did it manually and I am able to run it in the terminal.

But when I register it as an application in the Application Manager i get the error message:

> he Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web
> application through a Passenger-internal helper tool called the
> "wrapper". But Passenger was unable to execute that helper tool
> because it encountered an internal error.
>
> The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:
> /bin/sh: /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node: No such file or directory
> /bin/sh: line 0: exec: /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node: cannot
> execute: No such file or directory

The node I installed didn't go to */opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node* but in the bin folder of with path *home/userid/bin/node*.

Is there any way I can make Phusion Passenger look to my installed node path instead of */opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node*?

:)

Comment: Hi, have you solved that?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman we switched to another host who supported node

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Passenger (mod-passenger) and Nodejs from WHM's EasyApache. That would point Phusion Passenger to the latest Nodejs version and fix the issue. You do not have to do the installation from the terminal yourself.